# format date in file using awk

Tags: bash, date, awk

Content of the file is

```
Feb-01-2014     one     two
Mar-02-2001     three   four
```

I'd like to format the first field (the date) to `%Y%m%d` format

I'm trying to use a combination of awk and `date` command, but somehow this is failing even though i got the feeling i'm almost there:

```
cat infile | awk -F"\t" '{$1=system("date -d " $1 " +%Y%m%d");print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3}' > test
```

this prints out date's usage pages which makes me think that the date command is triggered properly, but there is something wrong with the argument, do you see the issue somewhere?
i'm not that familiar with awk,

Comment: It is pretty horribly inefficient to invoke `system("date …")` for each line.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `date` for this, its simply rearranging the date string:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {
    split($1,t,/-/)
    $1 = sprintf("%s%02d%s", t[3], (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[1])+2)/3, t[2])
}1' file
20140201        one     two
20010302        three   four
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
while read -r a _; do
   date -d "$a" '+%Y%m%d'
done < file
20140201
20010302
```

Answer (score 0):

system() returns the exit code of the command.

Instead:

```
cat infile | awk -F"\t" '{"date -d " $1 " +%Y%m%d" | getline d;print d"\t"$2"\t"$3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{var=system("date -d "$1" +%Y%m%d | tr -d \"\\n\"");printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", var, $2, $3}' file
201402010       one     two
200103020       three   four
```